# TypeError in python - missing 1 required positional argument

Tags: python

I'm stuck here. For `n = 5` and `k = 3`, the answer should be `19`. If I set `k = 3` separately as a local or global variable and run `wabbits(5)`, I get 19, but when I run `wabbits(5, 3)` after the function below, I get

```
TypeError: wabbits() missing 1 required positional argument: 'k'
```

What am I doing wrong?

```
def wabbits(n, k):
    if n == 1:
        return 1
    if n == 2:
        return 1
    return wabbits(n-2)*k + wabbits(n-1)
```

Comment: You are missing the argument k

Comment: `wabbits` function takes two arguments. first is `n` and second is `k`. but in code `wabbits(n-2)` means ur passing one parameter only.

Comment: You can't run `wabbits(5)` as that'd give you the same error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `wabbits()` function takes *two* arguments:

```
def wabbits(n, k):
#           1  2
```

but your code calls it with just one:

```
return wabbits(n-2)*k + wabbits(n-1)
#              ^^^              ^^^^
```

You need to pass in a value for `k` as well. You could just pass in the current value of `k`:

```
def wabbits(n, k):
    if n == 1:
        return 1
    if n == 2:
        return 1
    return wabbits(n-2, k)*k + wabbits(n-1, k)
    #              1    2              1    2
```

and indeed that produces 19:

```
>>> def wabbits(n, k):
...     if n == 1:
...         return 1
...     if n == 2:
...         return 1
...     return wabbits(n-2, k)*k + wabbits(n-1, k)
...
>>> wabbits(5, 3)
19
```

Comment: Your are simply genius. :)

Answer (score 0):

Calling the function with `wabbits(5)` will not work because the function is declared to accept *2* parameters: `n` and `k`. Both must be supplied.

You can call the function with two arguments, but the trouble is that the recursive call to `wabbits()` passes only a single argument:

```
wabbits(n-2) * k + wabbits(n-1)
```

This is two calls to `wabbits()` the first has *one* argument `n-2` and the second also has only one argument `n-1`. Since `wabbits()` must be called with two arguments a TypeError` exception is raised as you observed.

Answer (score 0):

Several solutions, the simplest is:

```
def wabbits(n, k):
    if n == 1:
        return 1
    elif n == 2:
        return 1
    return wabbits(n-2, k)*k + wabbits(n-1, k)

r = wabbits(5, 3)
```

However you could encapsulate `k` using an inner function:

```
def wabbits(n, k):

    def bunnies(rn):
        if rn == 1:
            return 1
        elif rn == 2:
            return 1
        return bunnies(rn-2)*k + bunnies(rn-1)

    return bunnies(n)

r = wabbits(5, 3)
```